# translate to pt-br Joi library with celebrate middleware

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, translate, joi

I have a code from the company I work for, unfortunately I don't have permission to share it with you but I still think I can be helped, I need to translate the warning messages into Brazilian Portuguese, but there is a problem, I need to somehow change the root or have all warnings already declared in celebrate and joi translated, since it is impossible to translate one by one, there are more than 100 routes and more than 1000 validations, how could this be done? These validations are only running on the backend, with node, express and typescript

I have already tried to use a library that does this but I was unable to implement the logic to solve the problem.